# Make UITableView cells less wide than the UITableView for large scroll area

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I would like to achieve the following view layout:

[image: View Layout]

A `UITableView` in the middle of my `UIViewController`'s view. As shown, the rows should *not* be as wide as the view - **that's easy: just make the table view smaller**, which is what I did for the screenshot.

However, as can be seen in the screenshot, this means that scrolling can only happen in the middle of the view. If a user tries to scroll by dragging on the grey areas left and right of the table view, nothing happens. The UI feels unresponsive.

So: is there a way to have both:

- Width of the table view **equal** to width of the enclosing view.
- Width of the cells **smaller** than the width of their table view.

---

I have tried to achieve this by setting the `contentInset`:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 0, 50)
```

but this just makes `contentSize` bigger, ie the cells are still as wide as the view but you can now scroll left and right as well.

Comment: Not quite sure what your trying to do. How are you creating the cells? Also you say you want the table view to remain the width of the view controller but looking at your graphic the tableview isn't as wide. You can see the scroll indicator is in the middle.

Comment: @latenitecoder I updated my question

Comment: Ahh makes more sense.  You need to create a custom cell that is the width of the tableview but make the content of that view the size you want. Make the cell's background colour clear and add a view in the centre just how you like it. It's the only approach that will get you the result I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert subview in cell content and make it as wide as you wish. Then make cell content view transparent and you are ready.

Comment: Thanks, such a simple idea! But `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()` still leaves a white content view. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I ended up setting it to `groupTableViewBackgroundColor`.